# Freemarker "string to hash conversion"?

Tags: spring-mvc, freemarker

I have a macro prints the string in hash format ( key / value ), when i use this value in spring macro freemarker throws error.

Here is an example

```
<@getContent /> - prints this string {"yes":"yes","no":"no"}

<#assign yesNoMap><@getContent /></#assign>

<@spring.formRadioButtons "model.somename" yesNoMap />
```

Basically i am using a spring macro to construct radio buttons and those labels and values are coming dynamically from a macro.

spring macro is throwing an error and its not recognizing the variable "yesNoMap" as hash.

Can anyone help me to convert that string prints in macro to hash?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try using `?eval`?

Comment: Yes i used eval, freemarker throws error "Expression & expected.... "

Comment: Here is the excat error message : freemarker.core.ParseException: Encountered "&"

Comment: Should this `{"yes":"yes","no","no"}` be `{"yes":"yes","no":"no"}` ?

Comment: you are correct, should be {"yes":"yes","no":"no"} that's my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not an answer to the question in the title, I think the following will solve your actual problem.

You can return your custom yes-no-map as a hash in the first place, saving you from converting it from a string to a hash, by defining a function instead of a macro. While macros only render textual output (which you then captured by an `<#assign>` directive), functions can return typed values, in your case a hash.

```
<#function getContent>
  <#return {
    "yes": "yes",
    "no": "no"
  }>
</#function>
```

Now this function can be called in any expression, e.g. assigned to a variable like you wanted to:

```
<#assign yesNoMap = getContent()>

<@spring.formRadioButtons "model.somename" getContent() />
```

or even used directly in the invocation of the spring macro:

```
<@spring.formRadioButtons "model.somename" getContent() />
```